# Asterisk and SIP behind NAT

Tags: nat, asterisk, sip

I am trying to Setup an Asterisk-Server to accept calls from a client in an other Network. The Server and the client are behind an NAT.

I have already activated STUN on the client, but I am still having problems hearing the other side on both. 
After some time, the call get's ended and on Asterisk logs a message about Retransmission Timeout reached and No reply to critival packet received appears.

Comment: Check the UDP Stateful/Dynamic Rule time-out on the NAT router. It's probably too short. I typically set it to 30 seconds to ensure SIP works correctly.

Comment: How did you configure the NAT device?

Comment: Be careful if the NAT device is a Cisco ASA or PIX firewall. If they have SIP inspection enabled, you need to configure Asterisk as though there is no NAT in place, because the firewall handles it all for you.

Comment: James, that was the most helpful comment ever.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest, lazy way around this is to set your asterisk box in a 1:1 nat config (often called DMZ host on home routers) and to make sure externip= is set in sip.conf.

The usual troubles with SIP and NAT are:

- SIP headers contain call source and destination information (IP addresses) that may not be reachable to/from clients and servers behind nat
- A generally broad range of ports need to be forwarded for RTP streams (the audio and whatever else)
- Many NAT devices (e.g. the Ciscos James Sneeringer mentioned) try to "help" and usually do a poor job of mangling the headers
- Some SIP devices will try to "reinvite", which basically means establish a direct connection with the calling device rather than route it through the PBX.  NAT completely breaks this.

Assuming you can't 1:1 NAT asterisk, try these:

In the general section of sip.conf:

- Make sure externip is set (externip=)
- Set nat=yes  (this is often overused/misunderstood, but try it)
- make sure localnet=/subnet mask  (e.g. 192.168.1.23/255.255.255.0) is set (this will cause asterisk to write its private IP to SIP headers sent to phones on that network, but use the externip everywhere else)

In the device section for the problem phone:
 - qualify=5000  (This will cause asterisk to check on the extension every 5 seconds.  Adjust as desired, as long as it's shorter than your NAT timeout it should keep the mapping preserved)

On your NAT/firewall
 - make sure the entire range of UDP ports listed in rtp.conf have forward entries to your asterisk server.  Typically this would be something like 10000-12000 (each call can use up to 4 RTP channels, so that setting would handle at least 500 simultaneous calls).  And of course 5060 (SIP signalling)

I've found this page helpful in the past:
http://asteriskguru.com/tutorials/sip_nat_oneway_or_no_audio_asterisk.html

If you're using one of the asterisk distros with a web-interface (FreePBX, Elastix, Trixbox, PBX-in-a-flash etc) let me know and I can suggest some GUI settings rather than editing conf files directly.  I've had the displeasure of debugging issues with most of them...

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that once you have setup the external IP address, you may not (and possibly should not) need to set up the local network address. Per James' comment: if your firewall is handling this for you, it can create an incredibly cryptic loopback situation.